# Copia de Pdf´s com itext campos não aparecem

Tags: java, itext

Tenho uma rotina que gera varios pdf´s com dados do banco, usando um template criado no OpenOffice, este contém vários campos que são preenchidos com os dados do banco, no final são gerados muitos arquivos, então faço a junção destes tendo como final um único pdf, o problema esta neste que valores dos campos não são visíveis porém, ao clicar em qualquer destes campos percebemos as informações.

Estou usando o itext versão 5.5.9 segue abaixo o método que cria o arquivo final, relato também que o problema esta apenas no pdf final, então como ou o que devo fazer para obter um PDF que seja a copia dos outros arquivos porque já olhei a documentação da biblioteca, já busquei informações de problemas idênticos ao meu e vi que existem mais não entendi como resolver.

```
private static void mergeFiles(List<PdfReader> readers, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    //copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();

    for (PdfReader r : readers) {
        copy.addDocument(r);
        r.close();
    }

    document.close();               
}

o que faz o rename dos campos

private static byte[] renameFields(String src, int i) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(form.getFields().keySet());
    for (String key : keys) {
        form.renameField(key, String.format("%s_%d", key, i));
    }

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

e o método que percorre a pasta que contém os arquivos que serão unidos/copiados
public static void unirPDF(String turma, String path, String destino) {

    File pasta = new File(path);    
    String arquivoDestino = destino + System.getProperty("file.separator") + turma + "_" ;

    ArrayList<File> arquivos;
    // Pegar apenas pdf
    arquivos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pasta.listFiles( new FileFilter(){
       public boolean accept(File pathname){
           return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
       }                
    })));

    try {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        //List<InputStream> pdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
        String cover =  path + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Cover.pdf";  
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(renameFields(cover, ++i));
        readers.add(reader);
        //pdfs.add(new FileInputStream(arquivoCover));

        for (File arquivo : arquivos) {

            if (!arquivo.toString().contains("Cover")) {

               //pdfs.add(new FileInputStream(arquivo)  );                        
               reader = new PdfReader(renameFields(arquivo.getAbsolutePath(), ++i));                   
               readers.add(reader);                                    

               if (i > 200) {
                   j++;
                   i = 0;
                   mergeFiles(readers, arquivoDestino + String.valueOf(j) + ".pdf" );
                   //pdfs.clear();

                   for (PdfReader r : readers) {
                        r.close();
                    }
                   readers.clear();
               }
            }
        }   

        if (readers.size()>0) {
           j++;
           mergeFiles(readers, arquivoDestino + String.valueOf(j) + ".pdf" );
           //pdfs.clear();
           for (PdfReader r : readers) {
                r.close();
            }
           readers.clear();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Fornecendo um código para que o comportamento possa ser reproduzido**

Fluxo a classe de serviço (ProdutoService) contem um método processar que obtém a lista de produtos e chama gerarPdfs passando esta lista

gerarPdfs ira usar o arquivo de template ( observação não vi como anexar este arquivo portanto sem ele ira ser difícil tentar reproduzir), e gerar os PDF´s com o conteúdo/dados de cada produto, um arquivo para cada produto, o template é simples só tem um campo que sera o nome do produto.

gerado os pdf´s vem o método UniaoPDF.unirPDF("G:\Dev", "G:\Pdf") que irá unir os arquivos em um só

```
class ProdutoService {
    public List<Produto> findAll() {

       Produto p1 = new Produto(1L, "Produto1");
       Produto p2 = new Produto(2L, "Produto2");
       Produto p3 = new Produto(5L, "Produto3");

       Produto[] produtos = {p1, p2, p3};

       return Arrays.asList(produtos);
    }

    void processar() throws IOException, DocumentException {

         List<Produto> produtos = findAll();

         gerarPdfs(produtos);

         // juntar pdf´s criados em um só
         UniaoPDF.unirPDF("G:\\Dev", "G:\\Pdf");        
     }

    void gerarPdfs(List<Produto> produtos) throws IOException, DocumentException {

         String template = "G:\\Dev\\ProdutoTemplate" + ".pdf";
         String arquivoSaida = "G:\\Dev\\Produto" ;  

         FileOutputStream saida = null;
         PdfReader leitor = null ;
         PdfStamper stamper = null ;

         // Gerar um pdf para cada produto
         for (Produto p: produtos) {

            saida = new FileOutputStream(arquivoSaida + String.valueOf(p.getId()) + ".pdf");
            leitor = new PdfReader(template);
            stamper = new PdfStamper(leitor, saida);
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
            form.setField("txtNome", p.getNome().toString());
            stamper.close();
            saida.flush();
            saida.close();
            leitor.close();     
         }
     }

  }



class UniaoPDF {
      public static void unirPDF(String path, String destino) {

           File pasta = new File(path); 
           String arquivoDestino = destino + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "produtos.pdf" ;

           ArrayList<File> arquivos;
              // Pegar apenas arquivos pdf da pasta
              arquivos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pasta.listFiles( new FileFilter(){
           public boolean accept(File pathname){
               return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
           }                
        })));

              try {

                  int i = 0;
                  List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
                  PdfReader reader;

                  for (File arquivo : arquivos) {

                     reader = new PdfReader(renameFields(arquivo.getAbsolutePath(), ++i));                   
                     readers.add(reader);                                                       
                  } 

                  if (readers.size()>0) {
                     mergeFiles(readers, arquivoDestino);
                     for (PdfReader r : readers) {
                          r.close();
                      }
                     readers.clear();
                  }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } 
      } 

      private static byte[] renameFields(String src, int i) throws IOException, DocumentException {
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
          PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
          AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
          Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(form.getFields().keySet());
          for (String key : keys) {
              form.renameField(key, String.format("%s_%d", key, i));
          }

          stamper.close();
          reader.close();
          return baos.toByteArray();
      }

      static void mergeFiles(List<PdfReader> readers, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {

          Document document = new Document();
          PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
          //copy.setMergeFields();
          document.open();

          for (PdfReader r : readers) {
              copy.addDocument(r);
              r.close();
          }

          document.close();             
      }

 }
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** do seu código para que seja possivel testa-lo e reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Olá Articuno , atualizei com o código para que o comportamento possa ser testado